# Javascript cache http get result

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm building a webpage, that presents data from database in a table. I would like to use HTTP GET to, well, get the data, but I would like to have it cached (I'm talking about client-side Javascript), so I won't have to send more requests for it.

I tried something with promises:

```
var get = function(aUrl) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                resolve(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }

        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    })
}  

this.getTableData = function() {
    get("http://localhost:3000/test")
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

I thought that I could store somewhere the result of the promise, but I can't find a way of doing that and it's probably impossible.

So, let me wrap it up: how can I use HTTP GET just once and have the data stored to reuse it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
var get = (function() {
    var promises = {};
    return function(aUrl, forceReload) {
        if (!promises[aUrl] || forceReload) {
            promises[aUrl] = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                // your code is unchanged in here
            });
        }
        return promises[aUrl];
    }
}());
```

This will return a new Promise, or the previously one that was created for the same url ... added a `forceReload` parameter because when I've used such a function, there are legitimate reasons for the logic

I would recommend you reject the promise when appropriate, otherwise you'll just have a perpetually pending promise, yet you should be able to determine eventually that there was an error or a non 200 response - so reject the promise in that case. But that's just a recommendation for sane code

Comment: This helped a lot :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable outside the promisified function to store the result.

Store the result in this variable when you get it.

Add a short circuit into your promisified function to resolve the promise immediately if the aforementioned variable is populated.

Alternatively (and possibly preferably), apply a memoize function to the promisified function, thereby separating the memoization logic from the logic at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I looked up memoizing, but all I found was Fibonacci examples. Could you explain how I can solve my problem?